# Error during reading output of "svn log" command

Tags: perl, svn

There is "svn: Write error" in case if I try to execute following script.
But if I disable line with "last" there are no any errors.
Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $repos = $ARGV[0];
my $rev = $ARGV[1];

my $repoURL = "file:///" . $ARGV[0];

open (SVNLOG, "svn log -r $rev -v $repoURL | ");

while (my $line = <SVNLOG>) {
   last;
}

close(SVNLOG);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `svn` process is trying to write to a stream (its standard output), and you closed the stream before it could finish.  If you don't want to see this error line, you will have to redirect `svn` standard error to `/dev/null`, or make sure you read *all* of its output before closing the file handle.

Comment: Why I do not have such error in following case open (SVNLOG, "ls -R $TRACEDIR | ");

Comment: Maybe the stream buffer is large enough to hold all of the `ls` output, and so `ls` actually finishes executing and terminates before you get a chance to close its output stream, and all of its output is hanging out in a kernel buffer.

Comment: Output of "ls -R $TRACEDIR" is larger than outbut of "svn log".

Comment: Then I guess `ls` just ignores that error and quits, while `svn` decides to report it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer you your question, but you should consider using [SVN::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mlanier/Alien-SVN-1.6.12.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm) from CPAN instead of using the svn command line tool directly.